# IRC - How to disable invite only on channel?

Tags: irc

I have created and registered an IRC channel, that way I can reclaim channel operator status upon re-entry. However, today I noticed this message from the server:

> Cannot join #my-custom-channel (Channel is invite only).

I received this message partly because the auto-join channel feature in XChat tried to join the channel before my user nickname authentication was successful with the server (so the server doesn't recognize me as a channel operator). Successfully authenticating with the server and recovering the channel has worked fine, but I would like to make the channel publicly available.

Which ChanServ command (or other command) can I use to disable invite only on the IRC channel so anyone can join?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the Invite Only mode on the channel, try the following command

`/mode #channelname -i`

You must have operator privileges in the channel to do this.

Depending on the services provided by the IRC server, you may need to remove invite-only via ChanServ in order for the change to be permanent, of course that depends on how you set the mode in the first place.

Check out the ChanServ help menu for further information on channel commands.

`/msg ChanServ help`

Comment: Thank you, the invite only has been removed. Hopefully this will stick forever now. FYI, I originally set up the channel with this command: /msg chanserv REGISTER #my-custom-channel my_password My Channel Description

Comment: That's fine - some Channel Services allow you to set permanent modes that are retained by the bot, even if there is no-one left in the channel. Some do it automatically, some do not :)

Comment: @Seidr do users need to be invited every time when this mode is turned on?

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job

```
/mode #CHANNELNAME -i
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are channel op you can type

```
/mode #channelname -i
```

to remove the invite flag